# Using a Jquery variable inside of a .html() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a Jquery if statement that displays different content inside a div using `$(".library-content").html("Here is some content!")` but I want a section of the content displayed to be dependent on a variable. So if the variable was set to "cats" the content might read "I like cats" and if the variable changes to "dogs" it would read "I like dogs". Is it possible?

here is my code, it is quite long so i tried to shorten it in my example,

```
 var librarycat = 'none' ;
 var librarytype = 'none' ;

$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#library-cat").change(function() {
  librarycat = $('option:selected',this).val(); 
  if(librarycat != 'none' && librarytype != 'none') {
        $(".library-content").html("{% set topic_posts = blog_recent_topic_posts('2941362257', 'audio', 25 ) %}<ul class='test-list'>{% for post in topic_posts|unique('name') %}{% if 'audio' in post.topic_list|map(attribute='name') %}<li><a href='{{post.absolute_url}}'><img src='{{ post.post_list_summary_featured_image }}' class='hs-featured-image'>{{ post.name}}</a><br>{% for topic in post.topic_list %}<a class='topic-link' href='{{ group.absolute_url }}/topic/{{ topic.slug }}'>{{ topic.name }}</a>{% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}{% endfor %}</li>{% endif %}{% endfor %}</ul>");
}
else if(librarycat == 'none' && librarytype != 'none') {
    $(".library-content").html("{% set topic_posts = blog_recent_topic_posts('2941362257', 'audio', 25 ) %}<ul class='test-list'>{% for post in topic_posts|unique('name') %}<li><a href='{{post.absolute_url}}'><img src='{{ post.post_list_summary_featured_image }}' class='hs-featured-image'>{{ post.name}}</a><br>{% for topic in post.topic_list %}<a class='topic-link' href='{{ group.absolute_url }}/topic/{{ topic.slug }}'>{{ topic.name }}</a>{% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}{% endfor %}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>")
}
else if(librarycat != 'none' && librarytype == 'none') {
    $(".library-content").html("{% set topic_posts = blog_recent_topic_posts('2941362257', 'audio', 25 ) %}<ul class='test-list'>{% for post in topic_posts|unique('name') %}<li><a href='{{post.absolute_url}}'><img src='{{ post.post_list_summary_featured_image }}' class='hs-featured-image'>{{ post.name}}</a><br>{% for topic in post.topic_list %}<a class='topic-link' href='{{ group.absolute_url }}/topic/{{ topic.slug }}'>{{ topic.name }}</a>{% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}{% endfor %}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>")
}
else {
    $(".library-content").html("{% set topic_posts = blog_recent_topic_posts('2941362257', 'audio', 25 ) %}<ul class='test-list'>{% for post in topic_posts|unique('name') %}{% if 'Insurance' in post.topic_list|map(attribute='name') %}<li><a href='{{post.absolute_url}}'><img src='{{ post.post_list_summary_featured_image }}' class='hs-featured-image'>{{ post.name}}</a><br>{% for topic in post.topic_list %}<a class='topic-link' href='{{ group.absolute_url }}/topic/{{ topic.slug }}'>{{ topic.name }}</a>{% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}{% endfor %}</li>{% endif %}{% endfor %}</ul>")
     }
 });
```

where you see the word 'audio' I would like this to be depended on a select element.

Comment: Yes, that is entirely possible.

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: It seems you already know about the `if` statement, and that it would be enough to solve your issue.

Comment: Sounds like just basic concatenation ?

Comment: I edited my post to include the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're new in town I'll help you out. In the future, please have a look at the help pages and provide some of your code.

```
if (firstThing === firstThing) {
    var myString = "Some words";

    if (secondThing) {
        myString = myString + "are pretty cool";
    }

    $(".library-content").html(myString);
}
```

Comment: I got this to work with my code, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use an if statement and local variables to set your message. The input to the `.html()` function can be a variable or static text.

```
$().ready(function() {
    var useCats = false;
    var catsMessage = "I Like Cats";
    var dogsMessage = "I Like Dogs";
    if(useCats)
      $(".library-content").html(catsMessage);
    else
      $(".library-content").html(dogsMessage);
});
```

```js
$().ready(function() {
  var useCats = false;
  var catsMessage = "I Like Cats";
  var dogsMessage = "I Like Dogs";
  if(useCats)
    $(".library-content").html(catsMessage);
  else
    $(".library-content").html(dogsMessage);
});
```

```css
.library-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="library-content">Original Content</div>
```

Comment: The thing is there are so many different options I would rather not have like 30 if statements.

Comment: be more specific in your question, provide a full code example, and expected output